# Convert except and interesect to left join and inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking for a software or framework to convert intersect and except to left join and inner join in sql server. I am planning to use some queries against vertica which does not have the set operators.

Does anyone know a framework or smth to programatically do this?

-- edit:

I have the query:

```
(((SELECT subscriber_id AS MSISDN 
  FROM   dbo.a 
  GROUP  BY subscriber_id) 
  INTERSECT 
  (SELECT subscriber_id AS MSISDN 
  FROM   dbo.b
  GROUP  BY subscriber_id))
 EXCEPT
 (SELECT msisdn AS MSISDN 
 FROM   dbo.c
 WHERE  balance = 123 
 GROUP  BY msisdn))
```

I want this to transform to:

```
select msisdn from 
(SELECT subscriber_id AS MSISDN 
  FROM   dbo.a 
  GROUP  BY subscriber_id) a
 join  
  (SELECT subscriber_id AS MSISDN 
  FROM   dbo.b
  GROUP  BY subscriber_id) b on a.msisdn = b.msisdn
 left join 
 (SELECT msisdn AS MSISDN 
 FROM   dbo.c
 WHERE  balance = 123 
 GROUP  BY msisdn) c on b.msisdn = c.msisdn
where c.msisdn is null
```

Answer (score 0):

An INTERSECT statement takes any rows that exist in both table A and table B assuming both tables have identical metadata.

The equivalent INNER JOIN for this would be to join table A and B where all fields in A were equal to all fields in B.

So for example if A and B have fields: key1 and key2 and data your queries would look like this:

```
SELECT A.key1, A.key2, A.data
INTERSECT
SELECT B.key1, B.key2, B.data;
```

The equivalent would be:

```
SELECT A.key1, A.key2, A.data
JOIN B ON A.key1 = B.key1
      AND A.key2 = B.key2
      AND A.data = B.data;
```

An EXCEPT on the other hand is the same idea in that A and B should share the same metadata except that the returned rows would be anything in A that does not exist in B (assuming that your statement was A EXCEPT B).

An equivalent LEFT JOIN would be A LEFT JOIN B on all fields in A joined to all fields in B.

Comment: Yea.. I know this. But I am looking for a framework or smth to do this for me.

Comment: Ah.. so you are looking for software to do this for you automatically? You may want to better state that in the question.

Comment: I did it: "Does anyone know a framework or smth to programatically do this?"

Comment: I would recommend changing your question to state "I am looking for a way to automatically..". As your question originally read, it was not clear that you were familiar with the difference between these  statements. In fact before you added your query above, it read just the opposite. I am sorry but I know of no converter tool available to do this for you. INTERSECT, EXCEPT, and JOIN syntax is part of ANSI SQL so where one is available usually so are others. You may have trouble finding others who have faced your situation. You may have better luck trying to write a program to do this for you.